# How to solve loss: nan & accuracy: 0.0000e+00 in a LSTM problem? Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-classification

I'm working in a **LSTM problem**. I'm trying to **predict MBTI** (Myers-Briggs test) personality type based on **text classification** (there's **16 personality types**).

I have a **csv file**, which was preprocessed: *the stopwords were removed, it was lemmatized, tokenized, sequenced and padded*. The file **doesn't have any NaN values and the text sequence have only int numbers**.

However, the problem is generated when trying to train the model I get:

`loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

[image]

[image: training model]

[image]

---

**As requested: how's the x, y data and label looks like with the results**

```py
print(validation_label_seq)
[[ 5]
 [10]
 [ 4]
 [ 4]
 [15]
 [12]
 [ 1]...]

print(validation_padded[0])
maxlen = 240
array([  23,  353,  147,  677,    1,    1,  409,   10,  845, 1530,    1,
        103,  107,  998,  117, 1389,   25,    1,   28, 1889,  165,    1,
       1520,   49,  718,   65,   55,   34,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,...], dtype=int32)
```

```py
print(train_label_seq)
[[ 8]
 [ 9]
 [ 3]
 [ 7]
 [ 4]
 [10]
 [15]
 [11]...]

print(train_data_padded[0])
maxlen = 240
array([ 19, 301, 133, 302, 562, 133,  28, 563, 895, 896, 897, 118,  99,
       564, 397,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0...], dtype=int32)
```

```py
results = model.evaluate(validation_padded, validation_label_seq)

test = validation_padded[10]
predict = model.predict_classes([test])
print(predict[1])

59/59 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[0]
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:342: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (proba > 0.5).astype('int32')

print(predict)

array([[0],
       [0],
       ...
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int32)
```

---

**What I tried?**

- I already tried to change to different optimizers
- Lower the batch size
- Check for value errors in the dataframe and in the sequences (train and validation data).

---

**Expected output:**
Maybe I'm building wrong the model, so I will explain which is the main idea. I would like to get one output or sixteen outputs, which determines the accuracy of your personality type.

```
1 output:
INTP: 89%

16 outputs:
ENTP: 5% | INTP: 81% | INTJ: 1% | ...
```

**If you'll like to check, here is the code:[mbti personality](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/MBTI_prediction.ipynb)**

**Dataframe:[mbti_df](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_new.csv)**

*Any suggestions to improve the question will be considered*

Answer (score 1):

You are using softmax in the code as final output. And it is bunch of probability values and check with what you are comparing within this code. The label encoded targets. They are not matching and that's why it is giving 0 accuracy. I would suggest changing the softmax o/p to correct form so that comparison over `accuracy` metric give the correct result.

Example:

soft max output `[0.2, 0.8]`
Output for other `[0 ,   1]`

Then it will be mismatch and accuracy will suffer.

Comment: Just change softmax to sigmoid? Because I get the same result. if the labels are not matching, I'm not understanding why.

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA.: No I don't mean that. All I am saying check the `y` and `predicted-y` and I think in this case they are not in the correct format. Because softmax sigmoid both will give that issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should find, because according to me, they are applied correctly. I'd attached the y data to the question, so you can give a quick look. Thanks!

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA add both predicted `y` and the true `y`

Comment: There's no predicted `y`, only train data and validation data (with their respecive labels). I assigned 80% of the dataframe to train data and 20% to validation data.

Comment: Your model is predicting something. I can see it. That's how these models work. Check what you are saying.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying, I thought about the `predict` function. Updated as you request!

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA.: Yes now tell me what your model is doing? It is predicting those y values right? Just check what that is...its output of softmax so its a fraction not matching with those integer label of actual `y`s

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA.: I guess you need to use `tf.Print` to look into the value? Thats how you would know what is there.

Comment: Please don't assume I know what you mean when you explain that I have to do something specific, I'm trying to guess what you were saying, I'm really new to tensorflow (this is my first proyect).

Comment: When I use `tf.print` in the `y's` and `x's` and in the `predict` method, I get the same values that I already wrote in this questions. E.g. `tf.print(predict)`, will print an array with a bunch of zeros, the same when I wrote `print(predict[1])`.

Comment: Look, my idea is simple. (x,y) -> `x=features` and `y=true labels`. Now your model takes those `x` after being trained on samples and predict something `y_hat`. Now compare those two. You would see what I meant. @GUNTERSAMA

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying, but I still don't see the issue. I attached the full code into the question as a github and google colab platform. Otherwise, If I can't get further, I will put this question for bounty. Thank you!

Comment: I finally understood the issue, is the model not the x or y. But still I can't find the adecuated model for this lstm problem, any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you can close this issue by answering the original issue and ask a new question for further feedback. That would be helpful for future users. @GUNTERSAMA